# How can I SSH into my desktop, which is connected via the university's WiFi?

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, tunneling

I'd like to SSH into my desktop, from my laptop. My desktop is connected to the internet via my university's WiFi. So, it's on a network that I have no control over and its IP changes regularly.

After some brief research, it seems that with the help of the server that I rent (which I have complete control over), this is possible by either:

a) SSH Tunneling
or
b) Setting up a VPN

So, here's the situation:

Laptop  <--SSH--> Server <--SSH--> Desktop

Here's what I want:

Laptop <---SSH---> Desktop (via the server as an intermediate)

Can anyone advise me on the easiest way to achieve this and/or link relevant resources?

If my desktop isn't connected to the server, is it possible to "ping" my desktop to initiate that connection from my laptop?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that you don't have access to your university's router as well, if so then your server will be behind a NAT, if so, please inform

Comment: I'm curious if your university has a network policy that speaks to accessing university resources from outside of the network?

Answer (score 1):

There are services to help you achieve this, one called [noIp](https://www.noip.com/) and another called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which are examples that offer a fixed domain for a dynamic IP, it basically gives you a domain, and each time your IP changes it updates that.
So to start,

make sure that the desktop(your server) you want to access has ssh_d service on a PORT *(any port > 1024 is fine)*

forward the PORT to the router *(note often routers use NAT between local connection and the Internet)*

connect to your server from another network using `ssh -p PORT user@the-domain.example`

Comment: updating the answer with a comment, there is another thing similar to noIP https://ngrok.com/ which is free

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with a reverse SSH tunnel. See here: https://www.vdomck.org/2005/11/reversing-ssh-connection.html

Comment: I rather make the reverse SSH tunnel the last option because of its disadvantages. check this question
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435638/what-is-the-downside-of-enabling-reverse-ssh-tunneling

Comment: @YousefAl-Hadhrami Thanks for the heads-up.